# react-router: beforeunload event not working for route change

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here is my code:

```
constructor( props ) {
super( props )
this.state = {
  newOrganizationCountry            : ''
}
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind( this )
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind( this )
this.handleChangeOfTimeZone = this.handleChangeOfTimeZone.bind( this )    

this.onUnload = this.onUnload.bind(this); // if you need to bind callback to this
    this.handleChangeOfStartDate = this.handleChangeOfStartDate.bind( this )
{ 
  /* 
  -> Time Zone detail
  -> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yury-dymov/react-bootstrap-timezone-picker/master/src/timezones.json
  */ 
}


onUnload(event) { // the method that will be used for both add and remove event
  console.log("hellooww")
  event.returnValue = "Hellooww"
}

componentWillMount() {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.onUnload)

}


componentDidMount() {
if(this.state!=null){
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.onUnload)
    }
}
```

This works when I close the window after changing something in the form and it asks me to confirm exit.
But I want it to work when I click to another page/link/route.
Please suggest me anything effective.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you click on any `Link` in react-router, the new link was push in your browser history. so this is just virutal changing link and have `preventDefault()`

you can't do this, but for example you can add a event to all links in your page to show a message when you want to exit current page.